# Magento 2 how to associate one customer with multiple companies

Tags: magento2, customer, b2b, company

**Magento 2 how to associate one customer with multiple companies.**

In Magento 2 admin, customer edit page we have a drop-down option Associate to Company, but I want it to make as a multi-select.

`company_advanced_customer_entity.customer_id` is Unique, I've removed the Unique index, and added a column `id` as primary key and then reassigned the Foreign keys relation.
`company_advanced_customer_entity.customer_id => customer_entity.entity_id`

Please let me know If anyone has any other approach or suggestion to complete this requirement, that will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In your `company_advanced_customer_entity` table:

`id` => primary key,

`customer` => foreign key linked to `company_advanced_customer_entity`.